# directory not created in ubuntu using java

Tags: java, file, ubuntu, filesystems

I want to create directory in ubuntu at location /opt/ and the code is

> File file=new File("/opt/myFolder");
>   file.mkdir();

executed successfully but directory is not created because the location is read only.Is there any way to give the write permission to ubuntu directory using java program.

Comment: Of course, if you're not either root or the owner of the directory, you won't be able to change permissions, as it would be a severe vulnerability.

Comment: You need to launch your jar file as root. 'sudo java -jar yourJar.jar'